# How to close I.E tab with xbap application

Tags: c#, xbap

I have a xbap application works in I.E. I have a button name close so what I want is when I clicked the close button it close current tab(which include my xbap app).I searched everywhere every site nothing found.

I tried

`System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^W");`

but it didn't work.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357308/how-can-i-close-the-browser-from-an-xbap work for you?

Comment: These code doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this in your code Environment.Exit(0);

Comment: Ok,I will try it then tell the result

Comment: Ok,I will be waiting

Comment: Not a problem :)